# Excel VBA Importing array conditionals

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have two arrays, with a bunch of conditionals evaluating over the data.

```
And Not Left(CStr(Cells(r, cA)), 1) = "8" And Not Cells(r, cH) = "-190001010000" Or Cells(r, cH) = "190001010000" Then
```

Right now I have all cells in row r and column cA  which begin with '8' going into array 2.

**But I want** all cells in row r and column cA while cell r, CH equals '-190001010000' or equals '-190001010000' to go into array 2.

I don't believe the latter half of my conditional statement is evaluating?

Here are the full conditions:

```
                        If Not Left(CStr(Cells(r, cC)), 3) = "722" _
                        And Not CStr(Cells(r, cC)) = "32DP2C" _
                        And Not CStr(Cells(r, cC)) = "325SFC" _
                        And Not CStr(Cells(r, cC)) = "78462F103" _
                        And Not CStr(Cells(r, cM)) = "Fofprice" _
                        And Not Cells(r, cH) = "-190001010000" _
                        And Not Cells(r, cH) = "190001010000" Then
                        'And 'Not (Left(CStr(Cells(r, cA)), 1) = "8") Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ()

```
And Not Left(CStr(Cells(r, cA)), 1) = "8" And (Cells(r, cH) = "-190001010000" Or Cells(r, cH) = "190001010000") Then
```

And I noticed "Not" right before the Cells(r,cH). Did you want it not equal to -190... or 190...?

Or did you want it when it's equal to -190... or 190...?

Comment: Then above code should work. You need to group "cell = 8 and (cell=-190.. or cell=190..)" using "( )". Otherwise it will look for "cell=8 and cell = -190" or "cell=190"

Comment: still doesn't work I was thinking of reordering and putting `Left(CStr(Cells(r, cA)), 1) = "8"` after the first test of equaling -190 or 190

Comment: Is there more conditions before those three conditions? or those three are the only conditions?

Comment: The above code seems like if any of those condition fails, it will not go into the "If Then". Is that what you are trying to do? For example, even the   Left(CStr(Cells(r, cC)), 3) <> "722"   , if    CStr(Cells(r, cC)) = "32DP2C"   then it will not go into the "If Then".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113439/discussion-between-mutjaylee-and-phillipsk).